# Can a function be rectifiable but have a discontinuous derivative?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, arc-length

All functions with continuous derivatives are rectifiable, but is the converse true?

Comment: Maybe piecewise differentiable functions…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Piecewise differentiable functions (i.e., those functions which can be seen as differentiable functions in each interval) are rectifiable without necessarily having continuous derivative.

Comment: In this case, is the arc length formula still valid? I believe it isn't given that its proof relies on the continuity of the derivative.

Comment: You can sum the arc lengths in each interval where the derivative is continuous.